# Using developer voice commands result in a network timeout error and hangs voice control

Tags: android, google-glass, voice-recognition, google-gdk

Since last Tuesday our project team have had some issues with the google glass device. We are working on an app that is using custom developer voice commands to launch and navigate through contextual voice menus within the app.

Our app has worked fine before, but now all of the sudden, developer commands won't work anymore. We have followed all instructions on how to setup the *AndroidManifest.xml* correctly for glass, and also how voice menu items should use the *strings.xml*. What's also interesting to note is that the problem seem to be unrelated to our app in particular. None of the apps we have tested so far with custom voice commands work.

The voice control hanging issue seems to be related to an inability for the device to connect to a remote (google?) server. Whenever we are connected through a wifi network and start our app, any voice menu with custom voice strings seem to hang. After about 30 seconds we see that logcat is printing the following: `824-1002/? I/ProtoRequestDispatcher﹕ Request failed due to network error [message=Read timed out].`After the timeout it sometimes tries to connect again to receive the very same error, or it goes back to the "ok, glass" menu. Sometimes (but not always) the voice control hangs without returning or trying to reconnect. Our last resort in this case have been to restart the device.

When we are not connected to any network we receive no timeout and the voice control doesn't hang. Any custom voice commands don't work here however. Pre-built voice commands that are present on the device work offline.

Another note is that some of the in-built voice commands won't work either, such as "Plus One" and "Dismiss Event". Like custom developer commands whenever we try to use these it gets stuck trying to connect to the remote server and timeouts. Without a network connection, these don't work either. A guess is that these also need to be downloaded once.

We have tried a variety of apps with custom voice commands. We have also tried to reset the glass device to factory settings, and created a new google profile. Switching to other wifi networks have so far not helped either.

Is there anyone else that have received this server timeout issue or that have any ideas of a solution to the problem? We're aware that developer commands require a network connection the first time they're used in order to receive a some sort of template to use when decoding it upon speech. We seem to get stuck before this stage though, and are very unsure how to proceed.